# C Programming to MIPS Assembly (for Loops)

Tags: c, for-loop, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm Trying to convert this C code to MIPS assembly and I am unsure if it is correct. Can someone help me? Please

**Question :** Assume that the values of a, b, i, and j are in registers $s0, $s1, $t0, and $t1, respectively. Also, assume that register $s2 holds the base address of the array D

**C Code :**

```
for(i=0; i<a; i++)
   for(j=0; j<b; j++)
       D[4*j] = i + j;
```

**My Attempt at MIPS ASSEMBLY**

```
     add $t0, $t0, $zero   # i = 0
     add $t1, $t1, $zero   # j = 0
L1 : slt $t2, $t0, $s0     # i<a 
     beq $t2, $zero, EXIT  # if $t2 == 0, Exit
     add $t1, $zero, $zero # j=0
     addi $t0, $t0, 1      # i ++
L2 : slt $t3, $t1, $s1     # j<b 
     beq $t3, $zero, L1,   # if $t3 == 0, goto L1
     add $t4, $t0, $t1     # $t4 = i+j
     muli $t5, $t1, 4      # $t5 = $t1 * 4 
     sll $t5, $t5, 2       # $t5 << 2
     add $t5, $t5, $s2     # D + $t5
     sw $t4, $t5($s2)      # store word $t4 in addr $t5(D)
     addi $t0, $t1, 1      # j ++
     j L2                  # goto L2
EXIT :
```

Comment: does it produce the same output?

Comment: i'm not sure, i have no way of compiling or testing, just beginning mips assembly.. :(

Comment: Won't `add $t0, $t0, $zero` keep the old (uninitialized) value of $t0?

Comment: @SanjeevPersad, surely you will be running in an emulator? Hand-debugging assembler is pretty painful! You can download the free MARS Simulator for MIPS here: http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/

Comment: tagged mars because this code appears to be written for a MIPS *without* branch-delay slots.  But what's your question?  You *need* to be able to test your code and see if it works, otherwise you're just wasting everyone's time without a [mcve].  Or did you mean to post this asm attempt as an answer for people to up/downvote based on correctness?  Looks mostly correct but highly redundant.

Comment: (And BTW, I only edited this because SO already bumped it randomly because there was no upvoted answer.  That makes the bump notice go away, in case anyone else was wondering, too.)

Answer (score 0):

`add $t0, $t0, $zero   # i = 0`  Nope, that leaves `$t0` unmodified, holding whatever garbage it did before.  Perhaps you meant to use `addi $t0, $zero, 0`?

Also, MIPS doesn't have 2-register addressing modes (for integer load/store), only `16-bit-constant ($reg)`.  `$t5($s2)` isn't legal.  You need a separate `addu` instruction, or better a pointer-increment.

(You should use `addu` instead of `add` for pointer math; it's not an error if address calculation crosses from the low half to high half of address space.)

---

**In C, it's undefined behaviour for another thread to be reading an object while you're writing it, so we can optimize away the actual looping of the outer loop.**  Unless the type of `D` is `_Atomic int *D` or `volatile int *D`, but that isn't specified in the question.

The inner loop writes the same elements every time regardless of the outer loop counter, so we can optimize away the outer loop and only do the final outer iteration, with `i = a-1`.  Unless `a <= 0`, then we must skip the outer loop body, i.e. do nothing.

Optimizing away all but the last store to every location is called "**dead store elimination**".  The stores in earlier outer-loop iterations are "dead" because they're overwritten with nothing reading their value.

---

You normally want to put the loop condition at the bottom of the loop, so the loop branch is a `bne $t0, $t1, top_of_loop` for example.  (MIPS has `bne` as a native hardware instruction; `blt` is only a pseudo-instruction unless the 2nd register is `$zero`.)  So we want to optimize `j<b` to `j!=b` because we know we're counting upward.

Put a conditional branch *before* the loop to check if it might need to run zero times.  e.g. `blez $s0, after_loop` to skip the inner loop body if `b <= 0`.

**An idiomatic `for(i=0 ; i<a ; i++)` loop in asm looks like this in C** (or some variation on this).

```c
 if(a<=0) goto end_of_loop;
 int i=0;
 do{ ... }while(++i != a);
```

Or if `i` isn't used inside the loop, then `i=a` and `do{}while(--i)`.  (i.e. add `-1` and use `bnez`).  Although MIPS can branch just as efficiently on `i!=a` as it can on `i!=0`, unlike most architectures with a FLAGS register where counting down saves a compare instruction.

---

`D[4*j]` means we stride by 16 bytes in a word array.  Separately using a multiply by 4 and a shift by 2 is crazy redundant.  Just keep a pointer in a separate register an increment it by 16 every iteration, like a C compiler would.

---

We don't know the type of `D`, or any of the other variables for that matter.  If any of them are narrow unsigned integers, we might need to implement 8 or 16-bit truncation/wrapping.

But your implementation assumes they're all `int` or `unsigned`, so let's do that.

I'm assuming a MIPS without branch-delay slots, like MARS simulates by default.

`i+j` starts out (with j=0) as `a-1` on the last outer-loop iteration that sets the final value.  It runs up to `j=b-1`, so the max value is `a-1 + b-1`.

**Simplifying the problem** down to the values we need to store, and the locations we need to store them in, *before* writing any asm, means the asm we do write is a lot simpler and easier to debug.

You could check the validity of most of these transformations by doing them in C source and checking with a unit test in C.

```
# int a: $s0
# int b: $s1
# int *D: $s2

# Pointer to D[4*j] : $t0
# int  i+j          : $t1
# int  a-1 + b      : $t2 loop bound

     blez   $s0,  EXIT                        # if(a<=0) goto EXIT
     blez   $s1,  EXIT                        # if(b<=0) goto EXIT
  # now we know both a and b loops run at least once so there's work to do

     addiu  $t1, $s0, -1      # tmp = a-1        // addu because the C source doesn't do this operation, so we must not fault on signed overflow here.  Although that's impossible because we already excluded negatives
     addu   $t2, $t1, $s1     # tmp_end = a-1 + b  // one past the max we store
     add    $t0, $s2, $zero   # p = D              // to avoid destroying the D pointer?  Otherwise increment it.

inner:                           # do {
     sw     $t1, ($t0)                 # tmp = i+j
     addiu  $t1, $t1, 1                # tmp++;
     addiu  $t0, $t0, 16               # 4*sizeof(*D)   # could go in the branch-delay slot
     bne    $t1, $t2, inner      # }while(tmp != tmp_end)
EXIT:
```

We could have done the increment first, before the store, and used `a-2` and `a+b-2` as the initializer for `tmp` and `tmp_end`.  On some real pipelined/superscalar MIPS CPUs, that might be better to avoid putting the increment right before the `bne` that reads it.  (After moving the pointer-increment into the branch-delay slot).  Of course you'd actually unroll to save work, e.g. using `sw $t1, 16($t0)` and `32($t0)` / `48($t0)`.

Again on a real MIPS with branch delays, you'd move some of the init of `$t0..2` to fill the branch delay slots from the early-out `blez` instructions, because they couldn't be adjacent.

So as you can see, your version was over-complicated to say the least.  Nothing in the question said we have to transliterate each C expression to asm separately, and the whole point of C is the "as-if" rule that allows optimizations like this.

Comment: In practice my inner loop is pretty similar to what GCC and clang emit: https://godbolt.org/z/cEGe4g.  But those compilers missed the chance to optimize away the outer loop.  Modern gcc9.1 does slightly better (for x86), e.g. jumping straight to the end on `b<=0`, unlike gcc5.4

Answer (score -1):

This similar C code compiles and translates to MIPS:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int a,b,i,j=5;
int D[50];
for(i=0; i<a; i++)
  for(j=0; j<b; j++)
    D[4*j] = i + j;
}
```

Result:

```
.file   1 "Ccode.c"

 # -G value = 8, Cpu = 3000, ISA = 1
 # GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404 (mips-mips-ecoff) compiled by GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404.
 # options passed:  -msoft-float
 # options enabled:  -fpeephole -ffunction-cse -fkeep-static-consts
 # -fpcc-struct-return -fcommon -fverbose-asm -fgnu-linker -msoft-float
 # -meb -mcpu=3000

gcc2_compiled.:
__gnu_compiled_c:
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $fp,240,$31     # vars= 216, regs= 2/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    .mask   0xc0000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,240
    sw  $31,236($sp)
    sw  $fp,232($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    jal __main
    li  $2,5            # 0x00000005
    sw  $2,28($fp)
    sw  $0,24($fp)
$L2:
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    lw  $3,16($fp)
    slt $2,$2,$3
    bne $2,$0,$L5
    j   $L3
$L5:
    .set    noreorder
    nop
    .set    reorder
    sw  $0,28($fp)
$L6:
    lw  $2,28($fp)
    lw  $3,20($fp)
    slt $2,$2,$3
    bne $2,$0,$L9
    j   $L4
$L9:
    lw  $2,28($fp)
    move    $3,$2
    sll $2,$3,4
    addu    $4,$fp,16
    addu    $3,$2,$4
    addu    $2,$3,16
    lw  $3,24($fp)
    lw  $4,28($fp)
    addu    $3,$3,$4
    sw  $3,0($2)
$L8:
    lw  $2,28($fp)
    addu    $3,$2,1
    sw  $3,28($fp)
    j   $L6
$L7:
$L4:
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    addu    $3,$2,1
    sw  $3,24($fp)
    j   $L2
$L3:
$L1:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $31,236($sp)
    lw  $fp,232($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,240
    j   $31
    .end    main
```

Comment: Compiling with optimization disabled gives nasty bloated asm that's not useful as an example for writing by hand.  Look at all the stores/reloads in your answer; nobody wants that and it's *far* from idiomatic MIPS code.